# How to convert big hex number (with decimal point) to BigDecimal

Tags: java

I have a big number in hex format (with decimal point) in a `String` and I want to convert it to a `BigDecimal.`

Example value: `0xcc.ccdp+1600`

In `BigDecimal` class, I don't see any function which takes string representing number in hex format as input and returns corresponding `BigDecimal.`

Is there a way to convert a big hex number from `String` to `BigDecimal?`

Comment: Yes, there's definitely a way.  If you would like a way that doesn't involve parsing the input string yourself, then I'm not sure.  I don't see any `BigDecimal` methods that accept any input in any radix besides decimal.

Comment: You could always bounce through `BigInteger`...parse either side of the decimal and then concatenate and parse. There's probably some fun ways to do it numerically also or subclassing BigDecimal to modify the char->digit mapping.

Comment: Note that, in theory, it's not a "decimal point" but rather a "hexadecimal point".

Comment: @HotLicks nice catch, word slip on my part.  It also raises a larger question, what does the hex number represent?  If it is a true hexadecimal floating point constant then this whole question is being approached the wrong way since it should map safely to binary without being subject to rounding errors so that would be the best route to BigDecimal.  If it's some kind of hybrid decimal/hex representation then it will need to stay closer to a string.

Comment: @MATTWhipple, it is a true hexadecimal floating point constant, and not some hybrid.

Comment: Yes, but with a binary exponent of +1600 it is too large to represent as a `double.`

Comment: Here's where these constants are [defined in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2).

Comment: BTW it's not a *decimal* point, it's a *hexadecimal* point.

Comment: @Bohemian ooh, that is wonderfully pedantic :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm surprised that `BigDecimal` doesn't already support this. I wrote the following, which I think should work. It passes my initial tests (with `0xcc.ccdp+0`, `0xcc.ccdp+1`, `0xcc.ccdp+16`, `0xcc.ccdp+256`, and your `0xcc.ccdp+1600`, and also some negative exponents, from `-1` down to `-16`), but it should be tested more thoroughly before being used in production code.

```
private final static BigInteger TWO = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
private final static BigDecimal MINUS_ONE = new BigDecimal(-1);

public static BigDecimal toBigDecimal(String hex) {
    // handle leading sign
    BigDecimal sign = null;
    if (hex.startsWith("-")) {
        hex = hex.substring(1);
        sign = MINUS_ONE;
    } else if (hex.startsWith("+")) {
        hex = hex.substring(1);
    }

    // constant must start with 0x or 0X
    if (!(hex.startsWith("0x") || hex.startsWith("0X"))) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "not a hexadecimal floating point constant");
    }
    hex = hex.substring(2);

    // ... and end in 'p' or 'P' and an exponent
    int p = hex.indexOf("p");
    if (p < 0) p = hex.indexOf("P");
    if (p < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "not a hexadecimal floating point constant");
    }
    String mantissa = hex.substring(0, p);
    String exponent = hex.substring(p+1);

    // find the hexadecimal point, if any
    int hexadecimalPoint = mantissa.indexOf(".");
    int hexadecimalPlaces = 0;
    if (hexadecimalPoint >= 0) {
        hexadecimalPlaces = mantissa.length() - 1 - hexadecimalPoint;
        mantissa = mantissa.substring(0, hexadecimalPoint) +
            mantissa.substring(hexadecimalPoint + 1);
    }

    // reduce the exponent by 4 for every hexadecimal place
    int binaryExponent = Integer.valueOf(exponent) - (hexadecimalPlaces * 4);
    boolean positive = true;
    if (binaryExponent < 0) {
        binaryExponent = -binaryExponent;
        positive = false;
    }

    BigDecimal base = new BigDecimal(new BigInteger(mantissa, 16));
    BigDecimal factor = new BigDecimal(TWO.pow(binaryExponent));
    BigDecimal value = positive? base.multiply(factor) : base.divide(factor);
    if (sign != null) value = value.multiply(sign);

    return value;
}
```

I've [released this on github](https://github.com/daiconrad/bighex) under the MIT license. There are unit tests, but only a pretty minimal set.

If you find any cases for which this returns an incorrect value, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution. I have done some initial testing and code worked perfectly. The only case, I can think of right now is when number stored in String is a negative number. Example -0xcc.ccdp+1600 . But it is not hard to add check for that.

Comment: Whoops! I missed that one. Good catch!

Comment: I updated it to handle negative numbers. Since `Integer.parseInt()` can also accept a leading unary plus e.g., `"+42"` I also made it ignore a leading plus sign.

Comment: I decided to rename the method `toBigDecimal`.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem while working with Alchemy APIs to covert token balances and I found this solution to work.
Unfortunately, `BigDecimal` does not support this kind of conversion. However, `BigInteger` does.

To do so, you first need to remove the '0x' at the beginning of the string, then get a BigInteger from it by specifying the radix, in this case 16, and finally convert it to a BigDecimal specifying the scale of the number you want to get, let's assume it is 18.

Here is an example based on the hexadecimal number you provided:

```
String hexNumber = "0xcc.ccdp+1600".substring(2);

BigInteger bigIntegerNumber = new BigInteger(hexNumber, 16);
    
BigDecimal bigDecimalNumber = new BigDecimal(bigInteger, 18);
```

Then you are good to go. Hope this helps